# Use Qt3D offscreen-rendered texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt3d, openglcontext

#### Goal

**I'd like to implement an actual widget for Qt3D since `QWidget::createWindowContainer` just doesn't cut it for me.**

---

#### Problem Description

My first approach of letting a new class subclass `QWidget` and `QSurface` was not successful since the Qt3D code either expects a `QWindow` or a `QOffscreenSurface` in [multiple](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/render/framegraph/qrendersurfaceselector.cpp#L191) [places](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/render/framegraph/qrendersurfaceselector.cpp#L214) and I don't want to recompile the whole Qt3D base.

My second idea was to render the Qt3D content to an offscreen surface and then draw the texture on a quad in a `QOpenGLWidget`. When I use a `QRenderCapture` framegraph node to save the image rendered to the offscreen texture and then load the image into a `QOpenGLTexture` and draw it in the `QOpenGLWidget`'s `paintGL` function I can see the rendered image - **i.e. rendering in Qt3D and also in the OpenGL widget works properly**. This is just extremely slow compared to rendering the content from Qt3D directly.

Now, when I use the `GLuint` returned by the [`QTexutre2D`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qtexture2d.html) to bind the texture during rendering of the `QOpenGLWidget`, everything stays black.

Of course this would make sense, if the contexts of the `QOpenGLWidget` and QT3D were completely separate. But by retrieving the [`AbstractRenderer`](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/render/backend/abstractrenderer_p.h) from the [`QRenderAspectPrivate`](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/render/frontend/qrenderaspect_p.h) I was able to obtain the context that Qt3D uses. In my `main.cpp` I set

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
```

The context of the `QOpenGLWidget` and of Qt3D both reference the same shared context - I verified this by printing both using `qDebug`, they are the same object.

**Shouldn't this allow me to use the texture from Qt3D?**

**Or any other suggestions on how to implement such a widget? I just thought this to be the easiest way.**

---

#### Implementation Details / What I've tried so far

This is what the `paintGL` function in my `QOpenGLWidget` looks like:

```cpp
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

d->m_shaderProgram->bind();
{
    QMatrix4x4 m;
    m.ortho(0, 1, 1, 0, 1.0f, 3.0f);
    m.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);

    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::Binder vaoBinder(&d->m_vao);

    d->m_shaderProgram->setUniformValue("matrix", m);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, d->m_colorTexture->handle().toUInt());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
}
d->m_shaderProgram->release();
```

`m_colorTexture` is the `QTexture2D` that is attached to the `QRenderTargetOutput`/`QRenderTarget` that Qt3D renders the scene offscreen to.

I have a `QFrameAction` in place to trigger draw updates on the `QOpenGLWidget`:

```
connect(d->m_frameAction, &Qt3DLogic::QFrameAction::triggered, this, &Qt3DWidget::paintGL);
```

I have verified that this indeed calls the `paintGL` function. So every time I draw the `QOpenGLWidget`, the frame should be ready and present in the texture.

I've also tried to replace the `m_colorTexture` with a [`QSharedGLTexture`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qsharedgltexture.html). Then I created this texture with the context of the `QOpenGLWidget` like this

```cpp
m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
m_texture->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA8_UNorm);
// w and h are width and height of the widget
m_texture->setSize(w, h);
// m_colorTexture is the QSharedGLTexture
m_colorTexture->setTextureId(m_texture->textureId());
```

In the `resizeEvent` function of the `QOpenGLWdiget` I set the appropriate size on this texture and also on all offscreen resources of Qt3D. This also shows just a black screen. Placing `qDebug() << glGetError();` directly after binding the texture simply shows `0` every time, so I assume that there aren't any errors.

---

The code can be found [here in my GitHub project](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-widget).

Comment: I developed quite big QML/Qt3D app with this:
May this work for you?
`
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/res/main.qml")));
  return app.exec();
}

import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
  Scene3D {
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right, actually I was already thinking about switching to QML but the rest of my app ([the one that I'm actually developing](https://github.com/florianblume/6d-pat)) is not in QML so I would have to adapt a lot - and I thought that implementing a Qt3D widget wouldn't take so long. Also, I need the 3D widget to be moveable by mouse (similarly to dragging a square around in MS Paint, I hope you get what I mean).

Comment: Hybrid mode app sounds feasible. Most of my code is in C++, though. But QML part simplifies things a lot.

Comment: How about https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qt3d-qwindow.html Not much info provided though.

Comment: The thing about the window is that it implements `QSurface` (because `QWindow` does and `Qt3DWindow` is a subclass). Now, I thought about sublcassing `QWidget` and `QSurface` and pass the surface to the `QRenderSurfaceSelector` of Qt3D but I don't actually know how to implement it (e.g. a function that returns `QPlatformSurface *`) and Qt3D internally expects a `QWindow` or a `QOffscreenSurface`, i.e. I would have to adapt a lot of Qt3D code which makes in infeasible.

Comment: Right now I'm at a point where I'm manually requesting the `QAspectEngine` to process frames and directly use the same context on the `QOpenGLWidget` and Qt3d which at least draws the clear color of Qt3D once - although it doesn't update anymore afterwards. I still don't understand why I can't use the texture from Qt3D with the shared context though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** (10th May 2021, since I stumbled upon my answer again):

My [Qt3DWidget implementation](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-widget) works perfectly now, the issue was that I had to call `update()` when the frame action was triggered instead of `paintGL` (duh, silly me, I actually know that).

---

Although I didn't find an exact solution to my question I'll post an answer here since I succeeded in creating a Qt3D widget.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-widget). It's not the cleanest solution because I think it should be possible to use the shared texture somehow. Instead, now I'm setting the `QOpenGLWidget`'s context on Qt3D for which I have to use Qt3D's private classes. This means that Qt3D draws directly onto the frame buffer bound by the OpenGL widget. Unfortunately, now the widget has to be the render driver and performs manual updates on the `QAspectEngine` by calling `processFrame`. Ideally, I would have liked to leave all processing loops to Qt3D but at least the widget works now as it is.

**Edit:**

I found an example for `QSharedGLTexture` in the manual tests [here](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/dev/tests/manual/sharedtexture). It works the other way round, i.e. OpenGL renders to the texture and Qt3D uses it so I assume it should be possible to inverse the direction. Unfortunately, `QSharedGLTexture` seems to be a bit unstable as resizing the OpenGL window sometimes crashes the app. That's why I'll stick with my solution for now. But if anyone has news regarding this issue feel free to post an answer!